# Why does 1 webform look different to another on the same drupal 7 site

Tags: webforms

I inherited a D7 website which has an existing `webform` that has a professional look. I am able to access this webform for editing purposes. When I add a 2nd `webform` to the site and use similar fields it doesn't inherit the same style with options not aligning correctly with their tick box, the tick box being smaller and using a different color.

The only thing that’s different is there was an “Application Form” of content type `Application` which has a url alias that when viewed shows the original `webform` but besides that I can’t see how it connects to 1 particular webform either from the webform to the page or from the page to the webform.

Can anyone point me to where I start looking to understand why 1 `webform` is styling differently to another on the same site?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the html tag and check CSS class and ID of all the element of the form. Looks like its easy to make fix in css.

Comment: What I don't understand is why a CSS class would not get applied to a webform. The div ids seem to be based off the webform properties but the class id is the same for the select components in both webforms

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML code of the webform that just includes CSS class and div ID and the css class that didn't work for you.